# I am new to Github and index.html is now displaying on github, What Am i doing wrong?

Tags: html, github, indexing, github-pages

I committed & pushed the content of index.html under a folder called site on my gh-pages, it was tested locally and the info was displayed but now on github it's not displaying when i go to 
https://norahg7.github.io/Myportfolio/    or https://norahg7.github.io/Myportfolio/Index.html
Also https://norahg7.github.io/Myportfolio/site gives an error 404.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <title> Norah portfolio </title>
 </head>
 
<body> 
 <header>
 <nav>List1</nav>    <!--Navigation -->
 <nav>List2</nav>
 <nav>List3</nav>
 <nav>List4</nav>
 <nav>List5</nav>
 </header>
 
 <h1> Hello welcome to my Porfolio</h1>

 <div>
 <p id="p1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
  </div>
<H1> Unordered list </H1>
<div>
 <ul>                 <!--Main unordered list -->
 <li>UI</li>
 <ul><li>Webdesign</li>  <!--Nested Unordered List -->
     <li>APP design</li>
     <li>Gamedesign</li></ul>
 <li>Web Development</li> 

 <li>UX</li>
 <li>Digital Art</li>
 <li>Voiceover</li>
 <li>Music</li>
 <li>Animation</li>
</ul>

</div> 
<footer>
  <div>Contact </div>
  <div> About </div>
     <div>About</div>

</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I deleted it and added the index.html manually and it worked, but when i commit from the pc, nothing display for some reason.

Comment: Notice the difference between Index.html and index.html

Comment: Awesome, Thank you so much, it's working as expected now. This solved it

Answer (score 0):

https://norahg7.github.io/Myportfolio/
This page shows content properly and is not showing 404 error. Only other two links shows error.

Comment: I deleted it and added the index.html manually and it worked, but when i commit from the pc, nothing display for some reason